# fibonacci sequence omitting numbers c

Tags: c

I'm trying to print out the Fibonacci sequence but the output doesn't match the expected output. I used the printf function and referred to the array where the data is stored, so I'm not sure where my mistake is. I'm getting strange output, too.

if m = 0, the loop that should print the sequence is designed to print the ith Fibonacci number should print out the 8 digits of each Fibonacci number.
for any other m, it stores n more spaces in the array for each m and the print function is designed to print accordingly.

Instead only the first 9 Fibbonacci numbers are printed when m = 0 and only the first 7 display the correct number of digits when m = 1.

I'm not sure where my mistake is.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int a, b, n;

    //create a list for the Fibonacci sequence
    printf("Enter n.\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

   //store a long for each 8 places

    int m;
    printf("Enter level of precision.");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    long fibonacci[(m+1)*n];
    fibonacci[0] = 0;
    fibonacci[1] = 1;
    for (int u = 2; u<((m+1)*n-1);u++) {
        fibonacci[u] = 0;
    }
    printf("F_0 =%d\n",fibonacci[0]);
    printf("F_1 =%d\n",fibonacci[1]);
    int j,l;
    for (int i = 2; i<n; i++) {
        a = i-1;
        b = i-2;
        fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[a] + fibonacci[b];
        fibonacci[n+i] = (fibonacci[i]-(fibonacci[i]%100000000))/100000000;
        fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i]%100000000;

        for (j = 0;j<m;j++) {
            fibonacci[(j+1)*n+i] = fibonacci[(j+1)*n+i] + fibonacci[(j+1)*n+a] + fibonacci[(j+1)*n+b];
            fibonacci[(j+2)*n+i] = (fibonacci[(j+1)*n+i] - (fibonacci[(j+1)*n+i]%100000000)) / 100000000;
            fibonacci[(j+1)*n+i] = fibonacci[(j+1)*n+i]%100000000;
        }
        printf("F_%d=",i);

        for (l = 0;l<(m+1);l++) {
            printf("%08d",fibonacci[(m-l)*n+i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

output:

for m = 0

```
Enter n.
20
Enter level of precision.0
F_0 =0
F_1 =1
F_2=00000001
F_3=00000002
F_4=00000003
F_5=00000005
F_6=00000008
F_7=00000013
F_8=00000021
F_9=00000034
```

for m = 1:

```
Enter n.
20
Enter level of precision.1
F_0 =0
F_1 =1
F_2=0000000000000001
F_3=0000000000000002
F_4=0000000000000003
F_5=0000000000000005
F_6=0000000000000008
F_7=0000000000000013
F_8=00000021
F_9=00000034
F_10=00000055
F_11=00000089
F_12=00000144
F_13=00000233
F_14=00000377
F_15=00000610
F_16=00000987
F_17=00001597
F_18=00002584
F_19=00004181
```

Comment: `long fibonacci[(m+1)*n];` heads-up: variable-length arrays are optional since C11, so it's probably not a good habit to have.

Comment: Use `%ld` for `long`.

Comment: `fibonacci[n+i]` might occurs out-of-bounds.(m=0)